# Where SharePoint installed app located in server?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I need to view and edit the SharePoint installed app files which is installed from SharePoint store .please suggest the app files located path in server.

Answer (score 1):

> When you install an app it creates a new site under the host site.
>   Most files of an app are stored in the folders of the site. For
>   example if you have a visual studio app project you have folders
>   called Scripts, Pages, Images, Content... The app Site will have
>   corresponding folders which contain the files. So you if you have a
>   tool like SharePoint Manager you can see the files of an app after it
>   has been installed.

[Read more here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99705b83-e1ee-4bbd-a76c-45c579e86444/location-app-file-in-sharepoint?forum=appsforsharepoint)

Also this one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48352344-bb7f-4d4d-9ee2-1f43305778b5/where-location-files-of-sharepoint-app?forum=appsforsharepoint